# How to automatically batch detect xls headers when the first row of xls is not headers in python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xls

I have 1000+ xls. I need to load them into pandas dataframe.
However, the first row of those xls are not always headers. Maybe second line, maybe third line.The headers for the xls are different. And the xls may contain some other information. How can I load them appropriately? The format I need is in the example4.

Here are some examples of the xls. (I could not upload screenshots yet)

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yxDC.png)

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqjwn.png)

[example3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o09z1.png)

[example4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG01M.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried use pandas.read_excel to read it. But I do not know how to ignore the "shopping list" row in the examples.

Comment: First step is to define exactly what "appropriately" means.

Comment: What 'appropriately' means is in the example4.